# Incredibuild, internal LD_PRELOAD error during compile

Tags: c++, linker-errors, ubuntu-18.04, incredibuild

I have freshly installed Incredibuild 0.93.85 on my new machine with Ubuntu 18.04 64bit.

The installation did not report any issues, but when I try to compile my makefile-project countless of those errors are reported:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/opt/incredibuild/lib/${PLATFORM}/libibinterceptor.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

The compilation itself runs through, though.

Obviously Incredibuild cannot resolve the ${PLATFORM} variable correctly. The folder /opt/incredibuild/lib contains the folders "i686" and "x86_64" and both contain a libibinterceptor.so

A colleague of mine has the same system config (Ubuntu 18.04 64bit and Incredibuild 0.93.85) and has no issues.

How can I get rid of those errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install the newest version of Incredibuild on the coordinator and the client (to date that is 0.95.14).